# Can I say "she made a good baby" to say "she was a good baby"?

Tags: past-tense

I know we can say "someone makes a good leader."  But can the same thing be used in past-tense  "he made a good leader." ?

Comment: Yes past tense is fine but using the idiom is weird for a baby.

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly grammatical and, providing the context made it reasonably clear, I'd understand what you meant. I would point out though that the construct is most frequently used to indicate someone performing a *role* well: for example 'made a good Hamlet' or 'made a good president'. Your sentence would sound natural if you were talking about role-play, for instance, but we don't normally think of babies as acting as babies so much as just being babies.

Answer (score 1):

> He made a good leader.

This is grammatical and sounds fine to me.

> She made a good baby.

This is also grammatical, but it sounds strange to me. I would not use the *so-and-so made a good X* construction unless *X* is a role or position, e.g. "he made a good teacher" or "he made a good uncle". You should probably stick with "she was a good baby", or alternatively consider "she made a good daughter" if you feel the need to use this construction.

Answer (score 0):

The title sentence is too ambiguous:

"She made a good baby"

Could be interpreted as referring to the mother rather than the baby:

"The mother produced a good baby"

Comment: yes i realize it's ambiguous.  But is it grammatically correct to mean what I want it to mean?

Comment: "She made a good baby" is no less correct than "She made a good cake"